# Whic to erms bgn a f - l qu?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, number-sequence, letter-sequence

Whic to erms bgn a f - l qu?

```
(a) ?,?,GN,B,U,PIK,AC
(b) ?,?,H,U,-,X,V,G,-,-,L,W,...
(c) ?,?,2,3,46,05,7,98,...
(d) ?,?,O,RM,TANG,-,F,D,-,P,L,-,-,X,_,_,J,_,_,Z,_,_,V,_,_,_
(e) ?,?,EN,CHMD,O,Z,QT,W,-,P,-,F,-,K,-,G,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,X,-,J,...
(f) ?,?,GL,TOS,CN,H,X
(g) ?,?,IE,FOR,-,H,QZ,-,ND,-
```

Source: *The GCHQ Puzzle Book*

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @u_ndefined Oh it's not spam! It's a puzzle :)  The strange way the question is written at the start helps you solve the puzzle (a bit).

Comment: Is the single space in (a) deliberate? (There are no spaces elsewhere in (a) or anywhere in (b) and (c).)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan No.  I will fix the odd spacing.

Comment: Are you sure that there should be two Bs in (a)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've got the *set* for (d), but the *ordering* is another matter entirely. This seems like a pretty interesting puzzle!

Comment: @Deusovi I can add e,f, g too if people are interested.

Comment: @Deusovi I also thought I had both of them but no clue about the ordering, then I found the key to the solution.

Comment: I am pretty sure the title reads $\ast$ (ROT13) Juvpu gjb grezf ortva jvgu n [fbzrguvat] $\ast$ for which $\ast$ (ROT13) gur zvffvat yrggref ner U, G, R, V $\ast$ but I still have no idea, overall :P

Answer (score 7):

Whic to erms bgn a f - l qu?

> I believe the rule here is that each letter can only be used once. The start of the sentence would be Whic(h) t(w)o (t)erms b(e)g(i)n ... I'm not getting much further yet, but I'm pretty sure that rule is correct.

<s>f - l could be</s>

> first to last, with the "-" indicating a missing word.

Presumably

> That reasoning extends to the four lines. Each being a list of things, with repeating letters (or numbers) discarded.  For example, in list 4) the fifth word (TANG) could be TANG(O), because the O is already taken. That would mean that the first two words could not contain the letters ORMTANG. No idea what the lists could mean though.

d) Is:

> Quebc, Whisky
>  It's letters on the keyboard (QWERTZ) in NATO code: Quebec, Whiskey, Echo, Romeo...

c) Is

> 1, -, 2, 3, 46, 05, ... It's Pascal's triangle <s>this number triangle I forgot the name of</s>, where you add a 1 and start and end and everything else is the sum of the two values on top. You know, the thing which goes: 1, 11, 121, 1331, 14641...

@Christoph solved a) and together with @MOehm b).

<s>I now believe the "question" is:</s>

> Whic(h) t(w)o (t)erms b(e)g(i)n a f(irst) (to) l(ast) qu(eue)

Again, @Christoph with the good solution.

Comment: qu could be rot13(dhrfgvba). Also, I do not agree with your **Presumably** part. If that were the case then rot13(gnat) would not have existed there in the question. But I do believe you are headed in the right direction

Comment: @R.D I'm pretty sure about the presumed part now. Each line is its own riddle with its own set of things and the question is just an example.

Comment: Hmm keep going. I can see what you mean now.

Comment: Bah!!! I've been spending ages trying to work out the entire sequence for D. Missed that the questionis just the first two terms!!!

Comment: Just a nitpick, but your c) is technically wrong. If you add the numbers the next number after 14641 would be 510105, and the following entries in the sequence wouldn't work out. Anyways, your answer is great, I wouldn't been able to start with mine if you hadn't done the ground work by figuring out the basic schema of the riddle!

Comment: Ah, yes you are right, I overlooked that. I blame base10 for misleading me.

Comment: This is very nice. I have added e,f,g now.

Answer (score 6):

Building on @nishuba's observation, namely that

> every letter only appears once per set.

The question could be:

> Which two terms begin each of the following sequences? 
>  (Thanks to @Mohirl for the last word)

Set a)

> **RED**, **Y**e**L**l**OW**, **G**ree**N**, **B**rown, bl**U**e, **PI**n**K**, bl**AC**k
> It's the color of snooker balls, ordered by value.

Set b). With a little help of Obi Wan Oehm:

> **FIRST**, s**ECOND**, t**H**ird, fo**U**rth, fifth, si**X**th, ... 
>  The ordinals.

Set c)

> **1**, 11, 1**2**1, 1**3**31, 1**46**41, 161**05**1, ... 
>  The powers of 11.

Set d) was solved by @nishuba.

Set e)

> **BUL**b**AS**au**R**, **IVY**saur, v**EN**usaur, **CH**ar**M**an**D**er, charmele**O**n, chari**Z**ard, s**Q**uir**T**le, ... 
>  Pokemons!

Set f) was solved by @Zandar.

Set g) was solved by @MOehm.

Comment: I believe your second word is slightly incorrect ;)

Comment: Your solution to b) works if there is a very first entry missing.

Comment: Regarding (b): rot13(Hfr gur beqf, Yhxr!). `:)`

Comment: Ah, that's right. Great solution.

Comment: I think the last word in the question is actually rot13(frdhraprf)

Comment: Very nice. I added e,f,g which I hope you will enjoy too.

Comment: I have to ask, how did you solve e)?

Comment: I was brainstorming words with the letters `CHMD`, when the solution came to my mind. A nice feature of the riddle is that you can easily verify if a solution is correct or not, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The answer for f) is

> Golf terms for scoring par and under (although the origin of the last two may just be a random edit on Wikipedia):
>  **PAR**, **BI**r**D**i**E**, ea**GL**e, alba**T**r**OS**s, **C**o**N**dor, ostric**H**, phoeni**X**.

Comment: Wow, well done! No wonder looking at the usual [sets of seven things](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1417:_Seven) didn't get me anywhere ...

Answer (score 4):

Partial addendum

(g)

> These are the ten hardnesses of the [Mohs scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohs_scale_of_mineral_hardness):
>
>  **TALC**, **GYPSUM**, calc**I**t**E**, **F**lu**OR**ite, apatite, ort**H**oclase, **Q**uart**Z**, topaz, coru**ND**um, diamond

Comment: This is great. How did you do it?

Comment: QZ stands out with its rare letters, so I looked for words that have QZ, but neither N nor D in them: quiz, squeeze, equaqlize, quartz, etc. We are also looking for a set or series of ten things and the Mohs scale fits.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial thoughts**

> Since the title is supposed to be somewhat of a hint, trying to complete it here- 
>  Which two terms begins and fills question mark? 
>  if correct, then missing letters could be clues, which are- h,w,t,e,i,n,d,i,l,s,e,s,t,i,o,n,m,a,r,k

Comment: That doesn't sound quite right.... "Which two terms begins..." wouldn't be grammatically correct. I suspect there's more to the title than missing letters.

Comment: There was  a small typo too. It should have been bgn not bgns. In return, I added (d).